# GMSPlace - can I get this from a set of coordinates

Tags: ios, api, gmsmapview, gmsplace

I have coordinates from a user tapping the map on the screen. Can I get the GMSPlace from the Google API by using the coordinates. Couldn't find anything in the documents or online that helped.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, never found anything on that. I'm thinking it would be really difficult, the sdk would have to know what map tile you were clicking on, at what resolution on what device, etc. etc. Too many variables probably to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you tap on a place, you can also get the place id, then use the place id to create a GMSPlace instance like this:

```
GMSPlacesClient *placeClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
[placeClient lookUpPlaceID:placeID callback:^(GMSPlace * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(!error) {
        [self updatePlace:result];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```